# Sympy Reuse the result of Solve in another solver

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, solver

Good afternoon,
I am having issues with my code. The code I am going to show is a simplified version of the actual one, but the idea is the same.

```
Var1 = Symbol('Var1')
Var2 = Symbol('Var2')
A = 20
B = 30
Var1 = solve(12+A*B+Var1, Var1)
Var2 = solve(Var1+A+B+Var2, Var2)
print(Var1,Var2)
```

What is the issue is that for example print(Var1) gives me back the numerical solution of the equation which is -612, but when it comes to print(Var2) it displays -Var1 -50 instead of recognizing that Var1 became a number.

This is the library I import:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
```

Any idea how to make it understand that Var1 became a number ?
I did try to assign a new variable and then use it in the Var2 equation but it gave me an error.

Answer (score 1):

[`solve`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) returns a list of (possibly multiple) solutions. `sol[0]` will give you the first (and in your case only) solution. you may then [`subs`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution)titute that solution in your second equation:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

Var1 = Symbol('Var1')
Var2 = Symbol('Var2')
A = 20
B = 30
sol1 = solve(12+A*B+Var1, Var1)                 # [-612]
eqn2 = (Var1+A+B+Var2).subs({'Var1': sol1[0]})  # Var2 - 562
sol2 = solve(eqn2, Var2)                        # [562]
print(sol1,sol2)                                # [-612] [562]
print(sol1[0],sol2[0])                          # -612 562
```